browserWindow not opening when Electron app is sandboxed
I am creating a browserWindow to perform Google auth for my Electron app. Before sandboxing, the window opens with no problems, but after I've sandboxed the app, the window won't open. Here's the code I have for creating the browserWindow below:
  let authWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    show: true,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      sandbox: true
    },
  });
  

I've looked into entitlements I may be missing but haven't come away with anything. Any ideas?
